# How to run a multiple regression for males and females separately?

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I have run the following multiple regression:

```
lm(distance ~ age*gender, data=mydata)
```

In my data gender includes males (coded as 0) and females (coded as 1). My results show that there is a significant effect of gender as a whole, and I now want to run two separate multiple regressions; one for males and one for females.

Can anyone offer some help on how to split this gender variable into just males and just females for my multiple regression?

Answer (score 2):

`lm` has a `subset` argument for this purpose, used like:

```
data(airquality)
lm(Ozone ~ Temp, data = airquality, subset = Month > 6)
lm(Ozone ~ Temp, data = airquality, subset = Month <= 6)
```

From the question alone this isn't something I'd suggest doing, but if you wanted thoughts on analysis you could post on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).